# Selenium Python - How to raise an exception and continue the loop?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I want to rasie an exception error if any mismatch found but also the loop should continue.
If there's any mismatch/exception error, the entire case should fail.
Can y'all check the below code and help me out here?

```
 def test01_check_urls(self, test_setup):
        #reading the file
        Total_entries=len(old_urls)            //Total_entries=5
        print("Total entries in the sheet: "+ str(Total_entries))
        col_count=0

        #opening urls
        while col_count<Total_entries:
            Webpage=old_urls[col_count]          //fetching data from 1st cell in the excel
            Newpage=new_urls[col_count]          //fetching data from 1st cell in the excel
            driver.get(Webpage)
            print("The old page url is: "+Webpage)
            page_title=driver.title
            print(page_title)
            Redr_page=driver.current_url
            print("The new url is: "+Redr_page)
            print("New_url from sheet:"+Newpage)

            try:
                if Redr_page==Newpage:
                    print("Correct url")
            except:
                raise Exception("Url mismatch")

            col_count+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a variable `url_mismatch`, initially `False`. Instead of immediately raising an exception when the is a URL mismatch, just set this variable to `True`. Then when the loop ends, check the value of this variable and raise an exception if the variable is `True`.

However, It's not clear how your `try` block results in an exception. Did you possibly mean (no `try` block necessary):

```
if Redr_page == Newpage:
    print("Correct url")
else:
    raise Exception("Url mismatch")
```

For now I am leaving that part of the code unmodified:

```
url_mismatch = False
while col_count<Total_entries:
    Webpage=old_urls[col_count]          //fetching data from 1st cell in the excel
    Newpage=new_urls[col_count]          //fetching data from 1st cell in the excel
    driver.get(Webpage)
    print("The old page url is: "+Webpage)
    page_title=driver.title
    print(page_title)
    Redr_page=driver.current_url
    print("The new url is: "+Redr_page)
    print("New_url from sheet:"+Newpage)

    try:
        if Redr_page==Newpage:
            print("Correct url")
    except:
        print('Mismatch url')
        url_mismatch = True # show we have had a mismtach

    col_count+=1
# now check for a mismatch and raise an exception if there has been one:
if url_mismatch:
    raise Exception("Url mismatch")
```

Comment: A good variant is to have a variable called `errors`, initialised to an empty list, then append a description of each problem as you encounter it. At the end of the loop, you can then go `if errors: raise Exception("There were %d problems: %s" % (len(errors), '; '.join(errors))`

Comment: @sabik: Yes, there are many refinements that are possible.

Comment: @sabik: That helped me. Thanks a ton

Comment: @Booboo: Thanks for the idea bro